# PUT _component_template yields "Incorrect HTTP method"

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to create a component template using the REST API, but even when pretty-much copying [the example from the official docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/indices-component-template.html) I am getting following error:

> *Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/_component_template/template_1] and method [PUT], allowed: [POST]*

I am a total noob to ES but it seems like the endpoint _component_template does not even exist in the version of ES I am using. (7.6.2)

#### The request

```http
PUT 127.0.0.1:9300/_component_template/template_1

{
  "template": {
    "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1
    },
    "mappings": {
      "_source": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "properties": {
        "host_name": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "created_at": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### When trying to go the POST-way

```http
POST 127.0.0.1:9300/_component_template/template_1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
  "template": {
    "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1
    },
    "mappings": {
      "_source": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "properties": {
        "host_name": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "created_at": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### The error

```json
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "invalid_index_name_exception",
        "reason": "Invalid index name [_component_template], must not start with '_', '-', or '+'",
        "index_uuid": "_na_",
        "index": "_component_template"
      }
    ],
    "type": "invalid_index_name_exception",
    "reason": "Invalid index name [_component_template], must not start with '_', '-', or '+'",
    "index_uuid": "_na_",
    "index": "_component_template"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Apparently ES thinks I am trying to create an index?

#### My ES details

```json
{
  "name" : "c61a464ba553",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "K_90ZfqzQkWaige2fz6GaA",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.6.2",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "ef48eb35cf30adf4db14086e8aabd07ef6fb113f",
    "build_date" : "2020-03-26T06:34:37.794943Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.4.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Comment: You are correct, ES thinks you are trying to create an index, this happens because the component template endpoint does not exist in version 7.6, it was implement in version 7.8+

Comment: @leandrojmp you should create an answer, since your comment IS the answer :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, the [component template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/indices-component-template.html) API was implement on Elasticsearch version 7.8, this endpoint does not exists on versions lower than 7.8.

This is the reason your elasticsearch thinks that you are trying to create an index and giving you the `invalid index name`.

On versions 7.6 you can create templates using the [templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/indices-templates.html) API.

Comment: Tbh even now, knowing this, I find it extremely difficult to figure that out from the documentation. Unless you put the "Index API" pages from both version next to each other... I am yet to come across a page that would mention "this is new since 7.8". Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, sometimes the documentation can be a little confusing. The tip is that if you are not on the last version, always choose your specific version in the sidebar on the right. Sometimes the changes are small, other it is something like this, new features.